# How to know file download status in ASP.NET MVC in clientside while using FileContentResult ActionResult?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have to know file downloaded status in clientside and I am using ASP.NET MVC to do the task. I cannot use cookies to know the status as the page is opening in iframe in some other application which doesn't allow me to keep cookies.

I would like to access the QueryString from RedirectToAction Url which is "**DownloadUrl**". My screenshot to get the value and respected view and controler code is as below. How can I achieve the "downloadStatus" querystring in my case? Please help.

[image]

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#download").on("click", function () {         
                $('#statusDiv').show();               
                setTimeout(checkDownloadStatus, 1000); //Initiate the loop to check the downloadStarted value.
        });

        var checkDownloadStatus = function () {

            // Get querystring value for downloadStarted
            if (getUrlParameter("downloadStatus") == 1) {             
                $('#statusDiv').hide();
            } else {
                downloadTimeout = setTimeout(checkDownloadStatus, 1000); //Re-run this function in 1 second.
            }
        };

        // get querystring value
        var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
            var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
                sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
                sParameterName,
                i;

            for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
                sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

                if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                    return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
                }
            }
        };

    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "formDownload" }))
{
    <div class="row">

        <div id="statusDiv" style="display:none;">File is downloading ...</div>

        <button type="submit" formaction="~/Home/FileDownload" id="download" value="download" formmethod="post">
            Download
        </button>
    </div>
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace RedirectToActionDemo.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> FileDownload()
        {
            var fileStream = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\Documents\Information.docx");

            DownloadFileResult res = new DownloadFileResult();
            res.FileResult = fileStream;
            res.MimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
            res.FileName = "Information.docx";

            TempData["Result"] = res;
            return RedirectToAction("downloadUrl", new { downloadStatus = "1" });
        }

        public ActionResult DownloadUrl(string downloadStatus)
        {
            DownloadFileResult res = TempData["Result"] as DownloadFileResult;
            return File(res.FileResult, res.MimeType, res.FileName.Replace("\"", ""));
        }
    }

    public class DownloadFileResult
    {
        public byte[] FileResult { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string MimeType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the last part of your url:

```
@{
   var id = Request.Url.Segments.Last();
}
```

[Some info about the above](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.segments?view=netframework-4.7.2)